# Can we add empty files in sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to add empty files in SharePoint site, if yes how. I am not able to and a project requires us to do it. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: What's the file type, and what is your definition of "empty"?

Answer (score 1):

What does not work for you? What have you tried?

Using [PNP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps):

```
Connect-PnPOnline https://my.sharepoint.com
$l = Get-PnPList Documents
New-Item C:\Temp\test.txt -ItemType File
Add-PnPFile -Path C:\Temp\test.txt -Folder ($l.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl) -Values @{Title="New File"}
Remove-Item -Path  C:\Temp\test.txt
```

Creates a new, empty file `test.txt` in the `Documents`-library.

Answer (score 0):

We can click the “open with explorer” in the ribbon.(classic experience)

Drag the empty file and folder into the library folder. Then the empty file or folder are uploaded to the library.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not possible or, at least, if it is a Microsoft document or has a common extension like TXT. But, here you have to approaches on how to do it:

- If you use "Open with explorer" button on classic experience, you will be able to drag & drop an empty file from your desktop, [here the link with the Q&A for SharePoint 2013](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/63019a96-5a3c-4491-a9bf-6e1ca13a9ab7/upload-empty-file-or-folders-on-sharepoint-2013).
- You can create a new file with Office Online (Word, Excel or PowerPoint) and save it in the library with no content, [here the link for SharePoint Online](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/66a828c1-7db5-4a36-a517-f1b33914d79e/sharepoint-online-i-am-not-able-to-upload-empty-files-can-we-allow-it-for-upload-somehow).

I didn't try any of them so cannot ensure that work. Hope this can be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution for this issue.

1. Click "Add shortcut to OneDrive" in the Share Point document library.
2. Open One Drive folder on your local PC
3. Wait for the folder to sync from Share Point to the local One Drive folder
4. Copy the empty folders to the local One Drive folder

The folder will be synced to the cloud in no time. The same goes for empty files.